# Postman tests - call "select all" API and for-each result, call "delete" API on it?

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, http, postman

I have two API endpoints:

1. select-all
2. delete

In a postman test collection, I wish to program it to: call the select-all API function, and for each result, call a delete API function.

How can I accomplish this, given you must declare each individual request?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand how you want it to work, let me know if I'm wrong.

Request 1 : get all the results (url, items, whatever ...) you want to delete and set them into an array (global var)
Request 2 : delete all these elements

If it is what you want, you will be able to make a loop in the 2nd request (delete) with using the set_nextRequest feature  (see http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/03/23/conditional-workflows-in-postman/).
Use another global variable, that you increment each time, to point to your next array item and call again the 2nd request.
When you're finished you set the next request as null to stop the loop.
That should work.

Alexandre